# VIVADO HLS Synthesis Error

Tags: c, dsl

No, for me it is not working. It's showing Error during synthesis: The top function `Adder` has no output. Possible causes are:

1. Output parameters are passed by value
2. intended outputs (parameters or global variables) are never written

Header file

```
#ifndef ADDERS_H_ 
#define ADDERS_H_ 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 

// Types and top-level function prototype //
int adders(int in1, int in2, int in3); 
#include "ap_int.h" 
typedef ap_int<8> in1_t; 
typedef ap_int<8> in2_t; 
typedef ap_int<8> out_t; 
void Adder(in1_t inA, in2_t inB, out_t sumAB); 
#endif
```

Test bench code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "ap_int.h" 
#include "Adder.h"

int main() 
{ 
    in1_t inA; 
    in2_t inB; 
    out_t sumAB; 

    inA = 15; 
    inB = 15;

    sumAB = inA + inB; 

    Adder(inA, inB, sumAB); 
    cout << "A = "<< inA; 
    printf("\n"); 
    cout << "B = " << inB; 
    printf("\n"); 
    cout << "SUM = "<< sumAB; 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

Comment: Difficult to follow the format in Stackoverflow, while pasting the content.

Comment: Adder has return type `void`. Are you just trying to add A to B? int Adder(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where you pointing out my error. I am unable to understand. Yes, i am adding Two numbers using VIVADO HLS 2014 3.1

Comment: First: the message is tagged with "vivaLdo" <-- there is an incorrect L in there. Secondly: What is the error it shows. Thirdly: why do you start you question with "No, for me it is not working."? Fourthly: where is the Adder.c-file code?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are passing the output parameter of the adder function by-value. In C, updates to such values are only visible inside the function and are not propagated to the caller. You should pass it by pointer or by reference, or simply by returning a value from the function as @jp-hellemons suggests. For example:

```
void adder(in_t inA, in_t inB, out_t& sumAB);
```

[Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) is a nice article explaining passing function arguments by-reference.